# how to select all select elements on the form except for those select elements with a certain class

Tags: jquery, select

the title is pretty much self explanatory. I need to select all select elements on a form except for those that have a class of ".notSelectable"

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourform select').not('.notSelectable')
```

or

```
$('#yourform select:not(.notSelectable)')
```

The first one is [generally preferred](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method

```
$("select").not('select.notSelectable');
```